# Software for performance testing

Tags: linux, performance

Is there a linux tool that acts like `ab` but for CLI, not HTTP.

I want the one that can accept CLI command, number of runs, number of simultaneuously run instances and gives some stats as a result.

Comment: @Nils: `ab` is the load testing tool for http. I need something similar for general CLI applications.

Comment: What is a general CLI application? What service interface does it expose if not HTTP?

Comment: @jasondbecker: it is an application that has nothing to do with web/http. `md5sum` for example

Answer (score 0):

Regards, zerkms
There are many performance tools available, but many of them are for one application or one user-case scenario. For example:

1. Network Performance tools:
   http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-linux.html
2. TSung: is a open-source multi-protocol distributed load testing
   tool. It can be used for Benchmarking and stress tests for several
   services including Apache, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Jabber/XMPP servers,
   etc.

Now for the Command Line, on Solaris and Linux, there are four tools that are the key rocks of many sysadmins:

- iostat: reports on the CLI the I/O statistics and the CPU utilization
- netstat: reports all network statistics
- vmstat: reports the memory utilization on the system
- sar: provides a combined view of all these statistics.

I recommend to you should read the man´s pages of these tools to learn to use them.
Thanks a lot for reading and I hope that this information will be useful to you.

Comment: Unfortunately your list doesn't contain anything relevant to the question